# Definite integral of ydx + xdy giving two different results

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, functions

This comes from Blundell's "Concepts in Thermal Physics". Section 11, example 11.1.

If I have $$df = d(xy) = ydx + xdy$$

Then one can do $$\int df = \int d(xy) = \int (ydx + xdy)$$

But  $\int df = \Delta f$ and $\int (ydx + xdy) = \int ydx + \int xdy =  yx + xy = 2xy$ and $\int d(xy) = \Delta (xy)$ by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

I don't get how can it do $\Delta f = \int_{(0, 0)}^{(1, 1)} (xy) = (1 \times 1) - (0 \times 0) = 1 $ which is different than $\int_{(0, 0)}^{(1, 1)} (ydx + xdy) = 2(1 \times 1) - 2 (0 \times 0) = 2$. What is wrong with my interpretation?

Comment: $\int y\,\mathrm dx = yx$ and $\int x\,\mathrm dy = xy$ can both fail, and usually will if you aren't going along vertical or horizontal lines.  Try, for example, the simplest path $(x, y) = (t, t)$ for $0 \le t \le 1$ from $(0, 0)$ to $(1, 1)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mistake here is $\int ydx +\int xdy=yx+xy$, where you took the other variable as a constant, which is not necessarily true and depends upon the path you take from $(0,0)$ to $(1,1)$.

Let me explain what I mean.

The integral in $$\int df = \int d(xy) = \int (ydx + xdy)$$
is a line integral whose evaluation depends upon the path travelled between the 2 points.

Let's say the path taken from $(0,0)$ to $(1,1)$ is a straight line as given in Figure 11.1(a).

Now, for a small step $dx$ taken in $x$ direction, $y$ also changes since the change in $df$ is taking place across a slanted line where both x and y coordinates change as you are moving across the curve and this is why you cannot treat the y in $\int ydx $ as a constant. Same goes for x in $\int xdy$.

The way to integrate line integrals like this is to parametrize the curve. In this case, the straight line path is $(t,t)$ for $0 \le t \le 1$.

Put $x=t$ and $y=t$ and integrate from $t=0$ to $t=1$.

$\Delta f =\int\limits_{C}\,d(xy)=\int_{0}^{1}d(t^2)=\int_{0}^{1}2td(t)=\left.t^2\right\rvert_0^1=1
$

note : $\int ydx=yx$ is only true when the taken path is a horizontal line because in that case, $y$ IS unchanging.